# Who is pushing commit

Tags: git, powershell

I have a PowerShell script that runs as a scheduled task on Windows Server and, pushes results into a GitLab repo. The admin who set this up, is no longer with the company and I would like to update the task to stop showing his name on the comit message.

In the script, I see the following lines:

```
git stage .
git commit -m "message"
git push origin master
```

Since I'm not seeing any credentials, I assume that is stored or he set this up to use a certificate but I don't know how to tell which. Once I know that, I should be able to figure out how to update it.

Comment: you would have to change the git user on the remote server. `git config --global user.email`

Comment: Yeah, but it is my info that's in there.

Answer (score 1):

Check the repo and the global configurations. `git config -l && git config --global -l`, then adjust user.name and user.email as required (either on repo or global)

```
git config user.name "Some guy"
git config user.email "someguy@foobar.com"
```

or with --global if it's global config.

Comment: what about the user that is running the task?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was logged in as. It is a service account that I assume I setup with global settings == me, for another job.

Comment: Perhaps the task itself has the author set up with `--author`?

Answer (score 0):

> Since I'm not seeing any credentials

This has nothing to do with the commit author name.

Check that the script (or the Windows session) does not use an [environment variable](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables#_committing) like `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME`/`GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL` or `GIT_COMMITTER_NAME`/`GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL`.

But if the local/config setting is set, it should be picking up those information.

Try and add a `git config --show-origin -l` in that script, in order to check what is going on at runtime.